# woocommerce js conflig issue with iso slider

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

i have installed woocommerce theme & recently added woo commerce grid/list plugin when i make it active plugin is not working , its pop up iso slider conflig error i try to solve but not able to solve this please any one van help me where is extly problem is rise.

Error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'iosSlider'

```
   <script>
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        /* items_slider */
        jQuery('.gbtr_items_slider_id_237278291 .gbtr_items_slider').iosSlider({
            snapToChildren: true,
            desktopClickDrag: true,
            scrollbar: true,
            scrollbarHide: true,
            scrollbarLocation: 'bottom',
            scrollbarHeight: '2px',
            scrollbarBackground: '#ccc',
            scrollbarBorder: '0',
            scrollbarMargin: '0',
            scrollbarOpacity: '1',
            navNextSelector: $('.gbtr_items_slider_id_237278291 .gbtr_items_sliders_nav .big_arrow_right'),
            navPrevSelector: $('.gbtr_items_slider_id_237278291 .gbtr_items_sliders_nav .big_arrow_left')
        });
    });
    </script>
```